# Cmake errors on mac after updating to High Sierra

Tags: macos, cmake, macos-high-sierra

after upgrading my mac to High Sierra I get the following cmake errors. I uninstalled it via brew and reinstalled it and the error stay the same. Any ideas what to do?

```
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeDetermineAlgorithmusCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_Algorithmus_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_Algorithmus_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: /Users/la/Desktop/test/CMakeFiles/3.9.4/CMakeAlgorithmusCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeDeterminefirsthit_Compiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_firsthit__COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_firsthit__COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: /Users/la/Desktop/test/CMakeFiles/3.9.4/CMakefirsthit_Compiler.cmake
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (project):
  No CMAKE_Algorithmus_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting the CMake cache entry
  CMAKE_Algorithmus_COMPILER to the full path to the compiler, or to the
  compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeAlgorithmusInformation.cmake
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (project):
  No CMAKE_firsthit__COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting the CMake cache entry
  CMAKE_firsthit__COMPILER to the full path to the compiler, or to the
  compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakefirsthit_Information.cmake
CMake Error: CMAKE_Algorithmus_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_firsthit__COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Have you tried the CMake.app too? I installed it and added the environment  var PATH by "/Applications/Utilities/CMake.app/Contents/bin". You can try it within a terminal at first.

Comment: How did you name the environment variable. I tried to set it in the cmake gui but the problem did not go away...

Comment: I just added it to PATH. See the postings in stackoverflow how to set PATH for MacOSX. For a short test you can do this within a terminal. `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Utilities/CMake.app/Contents/bin` In this case you have to run cmake from within this terminal.

Comment: @LaLa What was the result, did you have success with the issue?